Importrange with indirect
Im trying to pull data off another sheet using ImportRange which if i type everything out(=Importrange("URL","8!AD4") it works fine
I want to make the 8 in the "8!AD4" reference a cell in the sheet I'm working in. I tried to use
=Importrange("https://URL", INDIRECT(AI6) &"!AD4")
The error I keep getting.
I get Function Indirect parameter 1 value is '15'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.
I have the format set to plain text

Skip indirect; just go with:
=importrange("URL",AI6&"!AD4")


you should use =IMPORTRANGE("id"; AI6&"!AD4") as 2nd argument of IMPORTRANGE is already an INDIRECT
but for educational purposes here is an alternative:
=IMPORTRANGE("id"; ADDRESS(4; 30 ;;; AI6))


"id" - part of the URL between /d/ and /edit#
4 - 4th row
30 - 30th column = column AD
5th parameter of ADDRESS referencing the sheet name

